# Denormalized table and duplicated data

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, jdbc

My Java project uses pure JDBC for interacting with Oracle DB (v. 12). The transaction isolation level is Read Committed.

I have a highly denormalized table, which stores an entity in set of rows. I cannot change this. Unfortunately this table has to remain this way and the reasons are independent from me.

```
+------+------+---------+
| date | hash | ....... |
+------+------+---------+
| date | xyz  | ....... |
| date | xyz  | ....... |
| date | xyz  | ....... |
```

I have two columns identifying an entity - a date and a hash. Since each entity is stored as several rows, these columns are not really unique, or a primary key, but only indexed columns. Still I want to enforce a kind of "uniqueness", meaning that only one entity exists at the time, no matter how many rows is it made of.

Such entity can be updated couple of times a day, resulting in different values, but also different number of rows.

To make all this happen, every time I update an entity, I do two or more queries within single transaction:

```
delete from "table" where "date" = ? and "hash" = ?
insert into "table" values (?, ?, .....)
insert into "table" ....
... -- as many inserts as needed to store whole entity
```

This works fine for a single instance of application. Unfortunately, I have 2 instances working simultaneously, trying to store **exactly the same data** at almost the same time (they are simply primary-backup instances, but backup is also persisting - this I also have no influence on).

If this was normalized table, the solution would be to use MERGE statement, but it won't work here.

**My current solution:**

What I tried to do so far is to add one more column, an ID of the instance persisting, then executing INSERT statements using SELECT as a data source and putting condition to SELECTs that there must be no data for this date/hash and app ID, otherwise SELECT provides no data to insert.

I thought it would work, but apparently it does not. I still see duplicates. I think it's because two transactions do their delete at first, still don't see data yet to be committed by other transaction, thus perform inserts on their own. Then the "commit" is execute and boom. Both transactions insert their data.

**Other approaches that I considered:**

I guess also optimistic locking won't work, because at the final version check both transactions can still consider version to not be changed, while they are actually changed by both transactions at the same time and are about to be committed this way.

I know I could switch transaction isolation to SERIALIZABLE, but it isn't perfect either (first of all, Oracle driver will not serialize queries, but will do optimistic approach and fail with error in case of concurrent modification, I don't like that, it's a "programming by exception" paradigm, an anti-pattern, then the second disadvantage is performance of course).

Are there any other solutions to such a problem?

Comment: Just because you have multiple instances of your application does not necessarily mean that you can (or should) have multiple database instances.  The solution here I see as being the easy way out is to just have a single database.

Comment: You've got so many anti-patterns there already that claiming you can't use `SERIALIZABLE` because it's an anti-pattern is laughable.

Comment: Do INSERT statements always insert records with exacty the same date and hash values which then DELETE deletes ? Or maybe the DELETE deletes records with one date/hash (for example `2017-12-12`/`123`), but INSERTs insert other values within the same transaction (for example `2017-12-15`/`321`) ?

Comment: @Kayaman: the way how table is designed is not up to me, but the code which must work on it is done by me and this part I would like to keep out of anti-patterns as much as possible.

Comment: @krokodilko: DELETE deletes same date/hash as is then inserted. It's a way of doing UPDATE on arbitrary number of records (requirement is that number of records before and after update may change). Unless you know better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements, as I read them are:

- Database structure cannot change
- Both application must update exactly the same data at the same time
- Optimistic locking is out because it might cause errors or a performance degradation
- Pessimistic locking is out for the same reasons as optimistic locking

It seems like the most important thing is not what data you're changing but what data you are reading. You need a method of determining what data the users of your system (I can't tell whether these applications are just maintaining data or also using it) should be served.

I assume what your current queries for serving data are something like:

```
select * from table where date = :1 and hash = :2
```

If you change this to the following then you'll always select the most recent data and if there are duplicates in time you'll pick the first application (essentially random - change to whatever ordering you want)

```
select *
  from ( select t.*
              , rank() over (partition by hash 
                                 order by date desc, app_id desc) as rnk
           from table t
                )
 where rnk = 1
```

You can maybe put this in a view?

Then, you're able to essentially running two separate tables in a single table. You can use MERGE etc. and can change your DELETE/INSERT statements to:

```
merge into table o
using (select :1, :2 ... ) n
   on ( o.date = n.date
       and o.hash = n.hash
       and o.app_id = n.app_id
           )
 when matched then
      update
         set ...
 when not matched then
      insert (...

commit;

delete from table
 where date < :1 
   and hash = :2

commit;
```

where you're using the same date and hash from your MERGE statement. If the DELETE fails you don't really mind - you're protected from selecting the wrong data because you've changed your SELECT queries.

---

Personally, I'd acknowledge that one of your requirements have to change.

If there's any plans for adding additional applications I'd accept the performance degradation and perform updates on this table serially using a queuing mechanism.

If there's no plans for adding additional applications take the simple approach now and start using a locking strategy (not pretty) and just handle some known errors.

Comment: This seems to be correct approach (to deal with reading, not writing). Anyway, I'm wondering about the merge statement that you mentioned. I think it won't work, because MERGE expects to change only existing rows and not to change their number, while in my case number of rows can change. Am I right?

Comment: Merge won't get rid of the data that you no longer need. It will insert new data with the `WHEN NOT MATCHED` part. You will still need to do the DELETE afterwards but by focusing on what data you're reading you can even clear that up asynchronously if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

In order to serialize these two transaction I would create an additional table:

```
CREATE TABLE locktable(
  my_date date,
  my_hash number,
  primary key (my_date, my_hash)
);
```

and would change the whole transaction in the below way:

```
INSERT INTO locktable( my_date, my_hash ) VALUES ( date_value, hash_value );

delete from "table" where "date" = date_value and "hash" = hash_value;
insert ....
insert ....

DELETE FROM locktable WHERE my_date = date_value AND my_hash = hash_value;
COMMIT;
```

---

The first INSERT statement will serialize transactions due to the existing primary key constraint which prevents from inserting two duplicate records to the table.
You can see how it works by running a simple test using two different sessions and a default isolation level READ COMMITED.

---

First, let's create test data:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(
  my_date date,
  my_hash number,
  somevalue int
);

INSERT INTO my_table( my_date, my_hash, somevalue)
SELECT trunc( sysdate ), 123, 111 FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <= 3;
commit;

CREATE TABLE locktable(
  my_date date,
  my_hash number,
  primary key (my_date, my_hash)
);
```

---

**Sesion #1** - sees oryginal data.
We are going to insert a record into locktable, then delete old records and insert new ones.

```
SQL> select * from my_table;

MY_DATE      MY_HASH  SOMEVALUE
--------- ---------- ----------
01-JAN-18        123        111
01-JAN-18        123        111
01-JAN-18        123        111

SQL> INSERT INTO locktable( my_date, my_hash ) VALUES ( trunc( sysdate), 123 );

1 row created.

SQL> DELETE FROM my_table WHERE my_date = trunc( sysdate ) AND my_hash = 123;

3 rows deleted.

SQL> INSERT INTO my_table( my_date, my_hash, somevalue)
  2  SELECT trunc( sysdate ), 123, 222 FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 3;

3 rows created.
```

---

**Session #2** - this session doesn't see records inserted by the session #1 because it is not commited yet (`somevalue = 111`):

```
SQL> select * from my_table;

MY_DATE      MY_HASH  SOMEVALUE
--------- ---------- ----------
01-JAN-18        123        111
01-JAN-18        123        111
01-JAN-18        123        111

SQL> INSERT INTO locktable( my_date, my_hash ) VALUES ( trunc( sysdate), 123 );
```

When the INSERT is executed, then the session #2 "hangs" (is in a hold state), because Oracle detects that there is a duplicate record in the table `locktable` inserted by the other session, which is uncommited yet.
Oracle will now wait for what the first session will do:

- if the first session will do the COMMIT, then the duplicate error will be
  thrown in session #2
- if the first session will do the ROLLBACK, or will delete this row and will do the COMMIT, then the sessin #2 will be unlokced and the row will be inserted

---

Let's go to the **session #1** and do:

```
SQL> DELETE FROM  locktable WHERE my_date = trunc( sysdate) AND my_hash = 123;

1 row deleted.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

---

And now let's see what happened in **session #2**:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO locktable( my_date, my_hash ) VALUES ( trunc( sysdate), 123 );

1 row created.

SQL>
```

The session has been unblocked and continues to work.
Let's do another check:

```
SQL> select * from my_table;

MY_DATE      MY_HASH  SOMEVALUE
--------- ---------- ----------
01-JAN-18        123        222
01-JAN-18        123        222
01-JAN-18        123        222
```

**Now session #2 sees changes commited by session #1** !!!
This is because in [Read Committed Isolation Level](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/consist.htm#CNCPT1319):

> In the read committed isolation level, which is the default, **every
>   query** executed by a transaction **sees only data committed before the
>   query—not the transaction—began**. This level of isolation is
>   appropriate for database environments in which few transactions are
>   likely to conflict.

That is - the first transaction commited, then the second transaction was unblocked, then the second transaction sees the changes made by the first transaction, despite the fact that the second transaction started later than the first one.

---

Now we can continue work in the second transaction (delete old data and insert new one). If another (third) transaction starts (with the same date and hash), it will be again put on hold due to an existing record in the `locktable` table.

---

The above method will ensure correct serialization of **only this one transaction**.
If the application inserts or deletes records also in other places, it will not work properly unless other places are changed accordingly.

Comment: This is another interesting approach. While I believe it will solve the problem in its root cause, it requires another table, which - in my case - may be problematic. Still, it's quite good solution. I upvoted it, but I don't think I'll use it. Thanks!